# How to call a function when a competent got mount with props passed to it from parent component in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

I have a component called multiple time by passing props from parent , I just want to save those props in an object each time that component mounts in vue js

Answer (score 0):

To get all props passed to the component when it's mounted you can use `this.$props` inside `mounted` lifecycle hook.

Please see `src/components/Test.vue` in this example: https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-wzphj

---

You can find more information in the official documentation:

[`vm.$props` instance property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-props)

[`mounted` lifecycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted)

Comment: I am not able to access all props in child component it console undefined but when i see vue development tool it shows all props fine even if prints fine under {{}}. How to access them in a right way? also tried this.$nextTick

Comment: @DevanshDeep I added working example on Code Sandbox to my answer